# Android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

So i have this application on play store, which helps people clean their phone and i have gotten few errors messages that when people click "clean" button the app crashes and because of outofmemoryerror.
Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 147468 byte allocation with 24512 free bytes and 23KB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4215)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:977)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2842)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2774)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:220)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:206)
    at panda.cleaner.cleaner_batterysaver.fragment.SoftwareManageFragment$1.doInBackground(SoftwareManageFragment.java:139)
    at panda.cleaner.cleaner_batterysaver.fragment.SoftwareManageFragment$1.doInBackground(SoftwareManageFragment.java:127)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Here is the class where the error is coming from:

```
task = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<AppInfo>>() {
            private int mAppCount = 0;//(SoftwareManageFragment.java:127)

@Override
            protected List<AppInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                List<PackageInfo> packInfos = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
                publishProgress(0, packInfos.size());
                List<AppInfo> appinfos = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
                for (PackageInfo packInfo : packInfos) {
                    publishProgress(++mAppCount, packInfos.size());
                    final AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo();
                    Drawable appIcon = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);//(SoftwareManageFragment.java:139)
                    appInfo.setAppIcon(appIcon);

                    int flags = packInfo.applicationInfo.flags;

                    int uid = packInfo.applicationInfo.uid;

                    appInfo.setUid(uid);

                    if ((flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                        appInfo.setUserApp(false);//系统应用
                    } else {
                        appInfo.setUserApp(true);//用户应用
                    }
                    if ((flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 0) {
                        appInfo.setInRom(false);
                    } else {
                        appInfo.setInRom(true);
                    }
                    String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                    appInfo.setAppName(appName);
                    String packname = packInfo.packageName;
                    appInfo.setPackname(packname);
                    String version = packInfo.versionName;
                    appInfo.setVersion(version);
                    try {
                        mGetPackageSizeInfoMethod.invoke(mContext.getPackageManager(), new Object[]{
                                packname,
                                new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
                                        synchronized (appInfo) {
                                            appInfo.setPkgSize(pStats.cacheSize + pStats.codeSize + pStats.dataSize);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    appinfos.add(appInfo);
                }
                return appinfos;
            }
```

Since i am just a junior developer, i am not sure what the problem might be. Particular phone that caught this error was using Android 6.0.Help will be much appriciated. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: If you have a reference to your Fragment or Activity and the user rotates the screen you could be leaking AysncTasks and that would cause resources to be retained longer (life of the aysnctask).  

But I can't be sure until you post more code. You could try rotating the screen and seeing if you can recreate it. Good luck :)

Comment: 24512 bytes is equal to 0.02 mb. Take care of the memory your app uses. Use memory monitor tool from IDE.

Comment: The user can not even use the application on landscape mode, so the user cannot really rotate the screen? What code i should post more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the main problem i suppose. You should checkout the memory monitor for out of memory exception. First open the activity which occurs the error then press back button and check if there is any leaking.
There are few things you can do about this exception.
In android manifest, you should append largeheap = true under application tag.
You can load bitmap or drawable files with configuration and make their space lower

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the heap size dynamically but you can request to use more.

So, You have to add `android:largeHeap="true"` line in your manifest.xml file and your issue get resolved.

Something like this:

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application. It only applies to the first application loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results. Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

Reference: @Maveňツ answer